# How should I treat my covariate in R?

Tags: r, logistic, predictor

This is covariate age in my logistic regression. How should I treat it? Gets a little insecure. Have tried to read, but still insecure. 
Right now I treat it as if it were linear. A polynomial is not appropriate.
Some tips? I have a binary response variable

[image]

x axis is age, the y axis is the percentage of approved students first semester

Comment: "in R" appears irrelevant here. It's common in many fields to use age and age-squared as predictors. The point is not whether you expect a turning point but rather that the quadratic allows some curvature. If the squared term doesn't add much predictability, omit it.

Comment: Some other possibilities -- you could start with a linear term (on the scale of the linear predictor, presumably logit scale) and see if that's adequate, or you could fit some GAM-style term, such as a spline. Which of the various suggestions you might pick may depend on what you know or what you want to know, or what you're prepared to assume.